# Do Muggles refer to Magical cities and places by different names?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

Do Muggles also live in places such as **Godric's Hollows**, **Hogsmeade** and **Diagon Alley** as well as other towns and villages with magical populations? If yes, do they refer to those places using different names to the wizarding world?

Comment: I don't know about others, but Hogsmead is the only completely wizard dwelling in Britain

Answer (score 14):

I don't think that Muggles live in places like Hogsmeade or Diagon Alley because they are well protected not to be recognized from Muggles. But they could live in Godric's Hollow cause its just a "normal" village, just filled up with a lot of witches and wizards!

In the first book when Harry and Hagrid arrive in London and stand in front of the Leaky Cauldron, Harry mentions that it seems that only Hagrid and him can see the entrance to the pub and the Muggles just look over it as if it wasn't there. And since the entrance to Diagon Alley is in the back of the Leaky Cauldron, Muggles can't have knowledge of Diagon Alley.

Or just think about Hogwarts and how it is protected from Muggles: If Muggles come near, they just see an old ruin with a sign not to enter it because the roof could come down any minute. And if they still wanna go in, the Anti-Muggle-Spell comes into action and the Muggles feel a sudden urge to leave.

So Hogwarts and Godric's Hollow could be known by the Muggles (Hogwarts as old ruin), but Hogsmeade and Diagon Alley are too well protected to be known or to be habit to some muggles.

Comment: It's a somebody-else's-problem field!

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60019/4918 for a quote where Professor Dumbledore explains to the young Riddle that Muggles can't see Diagon Alley.

Comment: @b_jonas Muggles can't see the Leaky Cauldron, since that's the outward facing entrance to Diagon Alley right in the middle of a Muggle high street. They can see Diagon Alley itself, since Hermione's parents were able to see it. That does raise the question of how the hell they got to Diagon Alley if only their daughter was able to see the entrance, though.

Comment: I don't think that muggles just can't see the entrance to the Leaky Cauldron (->Diagon Ally) but their brains won't accept that magic is real and so they just look "over" the entrance as if it wasn't there. So for Hermione's parents it is clear that they can see it since their daughter is a witch and they accept the fact that magic really exists.
"Everyone just sees/believes what everyone wants to see/believe" ;)

Comment: @Naemy: so you say it's really a SEP field then?

Comment: At least for the Leaky Cauldron that may be! That would be a possible explanation why Hermione's parents can see it and the others don't.

It could also be kind of a protection like in "12 Grimmauld Place", that someone needs to tell you that the pub is there so you can see it. In the book Harry recognizes it after Hagrid told him it's there.
But there's no proof in the books since it's not mentioned that properly.

But all this doesn't count for Hogwarts or Hogsmead or the grounds for the Quidditch World Cup, since they really are surrounded with anti-muggle-spells.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, IIRC, Diagon Alley is invisble to everyone if they aren't inside.  In PoA, Harry stays at the leaky cauldron and mentions something along the lines of "hearing sounds coming up from the invisible alley below" (not a direct quote).  I took that to mean that no one, not even wizards, can see Diagon Alley from the outside.

Comment: I suspect the Muggles may just view Godric's Hollow as being full of eccentric neighbors. Like Sedona, Arizona. :p

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this answer:

- **In general, Muggles and magical folk seem to share towns/cities.**

  There are a few exceptions.

  Obviously, Diagon Alley, the Leaky Cauldron and the underlying streets are entirely hidden from Muggle eyes, as they’d instantly give away the existence of magic.

  And we’re told that Hogsheade is magic-only:

  > “Do you know much about Hogsmeade?” asked Hermione keenly. “I’ve read it’s the only entirely non-Muggle settlement in Britain —”
  >
  > — *Prisoner of Azkaban*, chapter 5 (*The Dementor*)

  Of course, this probably isn’t quite accurate. There are probably small hamlets and rural areas where you can only find magical folk, but which are considered insignificant. But it implies that all large settlements are a mixture of Muggles and magic.

  That would include Godric’s Hollow (and indeed, the Potters’s memorial mentions Muggles), and presumably other large towns and cities.
- **It seems likely that they use the same names.**

  When Hermione’s reading about Godric’s Hollow, we learn that wizards went into hiding in 1689. Prior to that, we know (from Pottermore, among other places) that wizards and Muggles mingled together. It seems likely that before the Statute of Secrecy, they used the same names for towns/cities as Muggles, and there’s nothing to suggest they tried to choose different names after the Statute was signed.

  Since place names change at a very slow place, it seems likely that they’re still using the same names for most places as Muggles. Here’s the relevant passage:

  > “Upon the signature of the International Statute of Secrecy in 1689, wizards went into hiding for good. It was natural, perhaps, that they formed their own small communities within a community. Many small villages and hamlets attracted several magical families, who banded together for mutual support and protection. The villages of Tinworth in Cornwall, Upper Flagley in Yorkshire, and Ottery St. Catchpole on the south coast of England were notable homes to knots of Wizarding families who lived alongside tolerant and sometimes Confunded Muggles. Most celebrated of these half-magical dwelling places is, perhaps, Godric’s Hollow.”
  >
  > — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 16 (*Godric’s Hollow*)

  (The three villages mentioned in that text are entirely fictional. That may imply that there is a large collection of magical-only villages, but too small to be compared to Hogsmeade.)

Comment: Note also that at least one of the three villages mentioned is known _not_ to be magical-only: Ottery St. Catchpole is the village close to where the Weasleys live, and there are specific mentions of Muggles living there (such as the girls the twins amaze with their ‘real magic tricks’ and the red-haired Muggle boy Harry is Polyjuiced into for the wedding in _Deathly Hallows_).